# How to integrate JIRA with AWS dynamodb service, If any story/task movement has been occured on jira dashabord it should reflect on the AWS dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, jira, atlassian-sourcetree

I have required any open source self hosted tools or any AWS integration methods for automating the AWS dynamodb and JIRA.

Anyone can help me on this scenario.

I have tried using automation field in JIRA dashboard , but it does not contain any direct tool for integrate or interconnect the aws dynamodb and JIRA.

I have expecting to connect the JIRA and dynamodb through tool via any integration method.

Need to reflect the JIRA data in dynamodb, whenever the story was updated.